How do I find the absolute maximum and minimum values of the Lamb-Oseen Vortex?
For an angular velocity function derived by Navier-Stokes, $$ \omega \left(r,t\right)=\frac{\omega _0R_0^2}{R\left(t\right)^2}exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{R\left(t\right)^2}\right)$$
from which the azimuthal velocity $u_\theta$ component of the vector field in cylindrical coordinates, $\vec{u}$, derived by vorticity, $\vec{\omega }=\nabla \times \vec{u}= \nabla \times \vec{u_\theta}$, is the vortex function,
$$v_\theta (r,t)=\frac{\omega _0R_0^2}{r} \left ( 1- e^{-\frac{r^2}{R(t)^2}} \right )$$
This is equivalent to the Lamb Oseen equation for some $ \Gamma_0 = 2\omega_0 \pi R_{0}^2$, where, $\Gamma_0$ is the initial circulation.
Question: How do I find the max/min values of $u_\theta$ for all $R>0$ assuming that $R_{0}>0$ in $ R(t)=\sqrt{4\nu t +R_{0}^2}$?
So far, to find the $r$ locating the max, I have taken the partial derivative of $u_\theta$ w.r.t $r$, set this equal to zero, and attempted to solve for $r$ in, $$\frac{\partial u_{\theta }}{\partial r}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial u_{\theta }}{\partial r}=\omega _0R_0\left(-\frac{1}{r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}}+\frac{2}{R^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}}\right)=0$$ which reduces down to a seemingly unsolvable form.
$$\frac{r^2}{R^2}=ln\left(\frac{2r^2+R^2}{R^2}\right)$$
I looked into the Lambert W function, but haven't turned up algebraically exact solutions. Using the abs-max value for $\omega(r,t)$, $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}},\:\frac{\omega _0R_0^2}{R^2}\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}}\right),\left(-\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}},\:-\frac{\omega \:_0R_0^2}{R^2}\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}}\right)$$
I approximated for $u_\theta$ to be, $$\left(\pm \:\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)},\pm \:\frac{\omega \:_0R_0^2}{R^2}\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}\right)$$
So far, I've been using, $$r \approx \pm \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{5}}= \pm 1.12099824328$$ which is the closest estimate of the solutions I've been able to find.
Is there an exact set of solutions to $\frac{\partial u_{\theta }}{\partial r}=0$ ?

I think you were on your way there with the Lambert-W function.
Let's define $\eta = r/R$, which yields:
$$\eta^2 = \ln\left(2\eta^2+1\right)$$
Rewritten as:
$$\exp\eta^2 = 2\eta^2 + 1$$
Now we must algebraically manipulate it into a form suitable for solving using the Lambert-W function, i.e. $W(x\exp x) = x$.
First step, match the exponential argument with an argument in the RHS of the equation:
$$\exp\left(\eta^2 + \frac{1}{2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=2\left(\eta^2 + \frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Second step, move the arguments to one side:
$$-\left(\eta^2 + \frac{1}{2}\right)\exp\left[-\left(\eta^2 + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right] = -\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Third step, apply the Lambert-W* function to both sides of the equation:
$$-\left(\eta^2 + \frac{1}{2}\right) = W\left[-\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] = -0.5, -1.75643$$
* Note: because the argument $x=-\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is between $-e^{-1}\leq x \lt 0$, there are two solutions.
Final step, solving for $\eta$:
$$\eta = \frac{r}{R} = 0, 1.12091$$
Substituting into the azimuthal velocity equation in terms of $\eta$:
$$u_{\theta}(\eta,t)=\frac{\omega_0 R_0}{\eta} \left(1-e^{-\eta^2}\right) = \frac{\omega_0 R_0}{\eta} \left(1+2\eta^2-1\right) = \omega_0 R_0 \eta$$
You also get two solutions

Wow! Thank you. In my research, I used the approximation, $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{5}} \approx 1.12099824328$ for its extraordinary accuracy to 1.12091. I still haven't solved this one after months of work.
